# "Microsoft Warning Alert" on Ubuntu computer

Tags: linux, firefox, scam

I get the "Microsoft Warning Alert" popup from firefox on a Linux computer.

That scam is described in https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-malicious-pornographic-spyware-riskware-detected-popup

How to clean it?

I cleared history and checked that there seems to be no add-on from the scam.

Is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should also purge **all** the browser's caches, clearing just a history is not enough. If you haven't used it from *root* user - this is OK, if you did - then chesk the new programs on your PC, some malware tries to drop a scripts on target PCs. If you're concerning about this kind of threats much - I'd like to advise you to use a simple but powerful open-source PC monitoring program called [Osiris](https://launchpad.net/osiris) - it will help you to detect any changes happened after the popup appeared.